# Overriding aspnetboilerplate app.component.html

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I am using [aspnetboilerplate](http://aspnetboilerplate.com/)  with asp.net core & Angular.
In my use case there is a requirement to show a page bypassing ABP default theme. For example; in general use, users will login to the application in which case the UI will be rendered within app.component.html and other views.

Then there is a publicly accessible url (no authentication) /api/services/app/action/[somevalue] which should return a view completely bypassing the standard structure.

How can I get such a thing done using ABP? I am not looking for a hack. Rather a solution within the best practices of the ABP framework.

Comment: `/api/services/` returning a view? That already violates "best practices".

Comment: er.. sorry :) wrong use of language. apis returns json data only :)

Comment: Create a module with its own layout, as done in [account](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/tree/45e9f45256055e51cbb211325fde3d0c8ff35dad/angular/src/account) module.